# Retrieving column names in R

Tags: r

I am trying to retrieve the column names of the data set model$data using the following formula:

```
sample(colnames(model$data),1)
```

When I run it I receive the following error message:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
```

Appreciate any help!

str(model) looks like this:

```
> str(model)
    List of 13
     $ data            :List of 1
      ..$ : num [1:1000, 1:56] 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 ...
      .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. .. ..$ : chr [1:1000] "7530" "5975" "552" "815" ...
      .. .. ..$ : chr [1:56] "Agriculture_and_Hunting" "Baking" "Biochemistry" "Braiding" ...
     $ unit.classif    : num [1:1000] 3 5 5 5 16 3 5 1 3 3 ...
     $ distances       : num [1:1000] 0.000806 0.000239 0.000239 0.000239 0.001953 ...
     $ grid            :List of 6
      ..$ pts              : num [1:25, 1:2] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
      .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. .. ..$ : NULL
      .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
      ..$ xdim             : num 5
      ..$ ydim             : num 5
      ..$ topo             : chr "hexagonal"
      ..$ neighbourhood.fct: Factor w/ 2 levels "bubble","gaussian": 1
      ..$ toroidal         : logi FALSE
      ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "somgrid"
     $ codes           :List of 1
      ..$ : num [1:25, 1:56] 0.000388 0.99996 1 1 1 ...
      .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. .. ..$ : chr [1:25] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
      .. .. ..$ : chr [1:56] "Agriculture_and_Hunting" "Baking" "Biochemistry" "Braiding" ...
     $ changes         : num [1:100, 1] 0.00261 0.00263 0.00262 0.00254 0.00254 ...
     $ alpha           : num [1:2] 0.05 0.01
     $ radius          : Named num [1:2] 3 0
      ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "67%" ""
     $ user.weights    : num 1
     $ distance.weights: num 1
     $ whatmap         : int 1
     $ maxNA.fraction  : int 0
     $ dist.fcts       : chr "sumofsquares"
     - attr(*, "class")= chr "kohonen"
```

Comment: Edit your question to show some summary information of `model` or better still a complete reproducible example showing us how to create a basic `model` object that exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: Hi, I already included the str for model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data boils down to something like this structure:

```
> str(model)
List of 2
 $ data:List of 1
  ..$ : int [1:3, 1:4] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "a" "b" "c" "d"
 $ foo : num 1
```

but you have some other components that we don't need to bother with, and my data doesn't have row names and is a lot smaller.

`model` is a list of 2 (for me) and 13 (for you) parts.

The `$data` component is also a "List of 1" component.

So `colnames(model$data)` is trying to get the `colnames` of a list, and failing:

```
> colnames(model$data)
NULL
```

Which you would have spotted if you'd tried running `colnames(model$data)` yourself.

You want the `colnames` of the first element of the list `model$data`:

```
> colnames(model$data[[1]])
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

and hence:

```
> sample(colnames(model$data[[1]]),1)
[1] "b"
```

Its possible that because this is a "kohonen" class object that there are functions that get these data matrices for you. You'll need to read the documentation to figure this out. What I've shown above is digging in the structure to find the data you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'll check it the documentation of the package.

Answer (score 0):

$ is not valid as part of the data set (or frame) name since R uses it to denote column name (:)) so R actually tried to get the column name 'data' from the data frame named 'model'
Try:

```
names(model)
```

And rename model$data to model

str(model)

```
> str(model)
List of 13
 $ data            :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:1000, 1:56] 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:1000] "7530" "5975" "552" "815" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:56] "Agriculture_and_Hunting" "Baking" "Biochemistry" "Braiding" ...
 $ unit.classif    : num [1:1000] 3 5 5 5 16 3 5 1 3 3 ...
 $ distances       : num [1:1000] 0.000806 0.000239 0.000239 0.000239 0.001953 ...
 $ grid            :List of 6
  ..$ pts              : num [1:25, 1:2] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..$ xdim             : num 5
  ..$ ydim             : num 5
  ..$ topo             : chr "hexagonal"
  ..$ neighbourhood.fct: Factor w/ 2 levels "bubble","gaussian": 1
  ..$ toroidal         : logi FALSE
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "somgrid"
 $ codes           :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:25, 1:56] 0.000388 0.99996 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:25] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:56] "Agriculture_and_Hunting" "Baking" "Biochemistry" "Braiding" ...
 $ changes         : num [1:100, 1] 0.00261 0.00263 0.00262 0.00254 0.00254 ...
 $ alpha           : num [1:2] 0.05 0.01
 $ radius          : Named num [1:2] 3 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "67%" ""
 $ user.weights    : num 1
 $ distance.weights: num 1
 $ whatmap         : int 1
 $ maxNA.fraction  : int 0
 $ dist.fcts       : chr "sumofsquares"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "kohonen"
```

Comment: Hi! the data is stored in different Matrices in the object model$data (or model[[1]] ). I am trying to retrieve the header of each matrix.

Comment: Maybe you need a @ .... Can you paste the result of `str(model)` ??

Comment: the object model is the result of the formula **som** from the package Kohonen to create Self Organizing Maps. str(model) is copied above.

Comment: str(model) gets a reply?