# How to get R Table Column Names

Tags: r, beginner

I could not find anywhere how I can do this seemingly simple task ([Retrieving column names in R](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17698/retrieving-column-names-in-r) was not helpful).

I have an R table defined as `sports_by_sex <- table(ais$sex, ais$sport)`. This is using DAAG's `ais` dataset. If I want to get the name of the sport at `sports_by_sex[, 2]`, how would I do that? When I `print(sports_by_sex)`, this is my result:

```
    B_Ball Field Gym Netball Row Swim T_400m T_Sprnt Tennis W_Polo
  f     13     7   4      23  22    9     11       4      7      0
  m     12    12   0       0  15   13     18      11      4     17
```

So for the example of `sports_by_sex[, 2]`, for example, I would like to get `Field` back.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution - access the index you want on [`colnames()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gpuR/versions/2.0.3/topics/colnames):

`colnames(sports_by_sex)[2]`, for example.